# Using awk/for/grep for comparing 2 files

Tags: awk, grep

I have 2 csv files whose contents are-

`expo1.csv`:

> 102,GREAT,adjective,ENG,p1_0,no,p2_1,no,p3,no,4,yes,p5_2,no,p6,yes....,su1,amb,su_09,no
>
> 104,BHAAG,verb,HIN,p1,yes,p2,no,p3_7,amb,p4,no,p5,no,p6_9,yes....,sg4_3,yes,su119,amb
>
> 110,.......,su11_0,amb

and
`impo1.csv`:

```
104,p1,no
102,p2,yes
104,p10,no
110,su11,no
```

Basically `expo1.csv` is a file on the server, and `impo1.csv` is a file I created to update `expo1.csv`. A script makes the changes in `expo1.csv` as specified in `impo1.csv` after performing slight processing in the impo1 data (eg. The line 102,p2,yes from `impo1.csv` is processed and then an update is made to `expo1.csv` - `p2_1,yes`.)

`expo1.csv` after changes:

> 102,GREAT,adjective,ENG,p1_0,no,p2_1,yes,p3,no,4,yes,p5_2,no,p6,yes....,su1,amb,su_09,no
>
> 104,BHAAG,verb,HIN,p1,no,p2,no,p3_7,amb,p4,no,p5,no,p6_9,yes....,sg4_3,yes,su119,amb
>
> 110,.........,su11_0,no

Now after the script makes the changes, we need to validate if the changes are done properly by comparing the impo1 and expo1 files. This is where i'm stuck.

So far I could isolate the data between the commas in `impo1.csv` separately into variables using `awk`:

```
Sno=104 102 104
Posw=p1 p2 p10
cho=no yes no
```

Now the question is, how do I check this? The `impo1.csv` files contains around 3000 updates. 
If I `grep p1 expo1.csv|grep no expo1.csv`, obviously it will not return the correct result as the file has many 'no' strings. I have tried using a for loop to separate the data using `awk` into separate variables and then grep using a wildcard - `grep sno expo1.csv|grep '/<$posw.*,$cho>/' expo1.csv` - but it doesn't work.

Using GNU bash 4.1.2.

EDIT - Should have mentioned this earlier, my bad - There are no clear patterns in the impo1.csv file which I can use to check the expo1 file. I have made corrections to the sample file contents which illustrate my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is rather simple. You just need to create a pattern from each line of `impo1.csv` and then `grep` it from `expo1.csv` after updated

```
validate() {
    # $1 ~ impo1.csv
    # $2 ~ expo1.csv after changes
    while read pattern; do
        grep -q "^$pattern" $2 || return 1
    done < <(sed "s/,/,.*/" $1 )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't clear enough in my explanation, sorry. Getting patterns from the impo1.csv file is very difficult. I have added the necessary explanation to the question.

Comment: @ShashankKR Does each line of `impo1.csv` contains only one update?

Comment: Yes@linerd one line contains one update.

Comment: Thanks @linerd, I've decided to use a while loop to do this, but instead of using read pattern i'm using read line.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '
    NR==FNR{
        for(i=1;i<NF;i)
            DATA[$1 SUBSEP $++i] = $++i;
        next
    }
    DATA[$1 SUBSEP $2] != $3
    ' expo1.csv impo1.csv
```

will print lines in `impo1.csv` which are different to data in `expo1.csv`

Comment: Note this shows in LQP review queue, probably because of the lack of explanation.